# Footer.php being inserted before article closing tag?

Tags: hooks, footer

I have set up a child theme to 2016. I must have done -something- because the footer.php in the child theme is being inserted immediately after the .entry-footer tag (immediately before the closing article tag) and NOT where I expect it.

The net effect is that I'm having the same footer.php code occurring after each article on the blog page and -not- at the true page footer as I expect.

How do I determine why this is occurring?

Here is the code for my INDEX.PHP (Although I want to make it clear that the code is appearing in the wrong spot -also- on single pages and posts.)

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
            // Start the loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.

        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/346126/edit) to add any relevant code (eg, the `index.php` or `home.php` file, if this is happening in the blog post list).

Comment: INDEX.PHP added to question

Comment: And how do the files `template-parts/content-X` look like?